# 4-bonacci ratio Limit

Tags: real-analysis, fibonacci-numbers, continued-fractions

Define the $k$-bonacci numbers as such:

$$f^k_0=0, f^k_1=1, ..., f^k_{k-1}=k-1, k>1$$
$$f^k_{n+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} f^k_{n-j}, n\ge k$$

Then define $$r^k_n=\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}$$

Then if $L_k=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}r^k_n$, what is $L_k$?

I am assuming that the limit exists.  My question is the process.  If $k=2$, then we have

$$L_2=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}r^2_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^2_{n+1}}{f^2_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^2_{n}+f^2_{n-1}}{f^2_{n}}=1+\frac{1}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^2_{n}}{f^2_{n-1}}}=1+\frac{1}{L_2}$$

and then you can use the quadratic formula to solve.  You can do the same thing for $k=3$, albeit much more work...

$$L_3=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^3_{n+1}}{f^3_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^3_{n}+f^3_{n-1}+f^3_{n-2}}{f^2_{n}}=1+\frac{1}{L_3}+\frac{1}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^3_{n}}{f^3_{n-2}}}$$

$$=1+\frac{1}{L_3}+\frac{1}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^3_{n-1}+f^3_{n-2}+f^3_{n-3}}{f^3_{n-2}}}=1+\frac{1}{L_3}+\frac{1}{L_3+1+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^3_{n-3}}{f^3_{n-2}}}$$

$$=1+\frac{1}{L_3}+\frac{1}{L_3+1+\frac{1}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^3_{n-2}}{f^3_{n-3}}}}=1+\frac{1}{L_3}+\frac{1}{L_3+1+\frac{1}{L_3}}$$

Rearranging then requires solving the quartic $x^4-2x^2-2x-1=0$, which is not too bad.  However, this method seems to fall apart.  Is it possible to prove (is it even true?) that this process does not work for $k>3$? Or does it work and it just is a relatively large sum of continued fractions?

Comment: The first line contradicts the next line.

Comment: I think i fixed it...

Comment: You haven't shown that the limit exists either, you merely assume that it does.

Comment: Okay.  I am assuming the limit exists....

Comment: The first line still doesn't make sense.  I think you just want $f_1^k=1$

Comment: k is not a power...it is just an indicator that we are adding up the first k terms and this is defining the recursive relationship.

Comment: I can see that, but it does not agree with anything.  If the first line is correct, $L_k=1$

Comment: So are you saying I should define it so that $k>1$?

Comment: No, you should just leave it at $f_1^k=1$ so that we can have $f_2^k=\sum f_{n-j}^k$, etc.

Comment: I think it would work for all $k$ in principle, it would just be hellishly complicated. Less work is to look at the zeros of $p_k(x) = x^k - x^{k-1} - x^{k-2} - \dotsc - x - 1$. Let's call them $\alpha_1,\dotsc, \alpha_k$ (if $p_k$ has zeros of multiplicity $> 1$, things are a bit different, but I think these $p_k$ all have only simple zeros), then there are coefficients $c_r$ - depending on the choice of $f^k_0,\dotsc, f^k_{k-1}$ - such that $$f^k_n = \sum_{r = 1}^k c_r\cdot \alpha_r^n.$$ Then $L_k = \max \{ \lvert\alpha_r\rvert : c_r \neq 0\}$.

Comment: In almost all cases, that is the largest real zero $\zeta_k$ of $p_k$, which lies between $1$ and $2$, with $\zeta_k \to 2$ as $k\to\infty$. Finding a closed form for $\zeta_k$ for $k > 4$ is probably impossible.

Comment: Daniel makes a good point.  You must also determine which root of said polynomials are the limit.

Comment: Okay.  That was my hunch which was why I was inquiring in the first place, that the polynomial mentioned above by Daniel was ultimately going to give the Limit needed.  So the recursive definition yields a characteristic polynomial that gives the answer...

Comment: @DanielFischer, if you type up an answer, I can upvote you.

Comment: It would serve as an answer to the question "what is $L_k$", but not to the questions at the end of your post. Which is your primary point of interest?

Comment: No, I know.  I went through the process of trying to use the method above because that was one way I knew how to find the limit and as you mentioned, it is "hellishly complicated"...  Obviously the polynomial method is best.  Thank you.